# post method in php

Tags: php, android

I am trying to send data through post method in android . But how I can receive data in server. My server is in php. I found a method in php $_post[]. how can i use it? 
my client code is

```
client=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/php_server/index.php");
            HttpEntity entity;

            try
            {
                StringEntity string=new StringEntity("I am android");

                 entity=string;
                 request.setEntity(entity);

                HttpResponse response=client.execute(request);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("socket connection", e.toString());
            }
```

Comment: Btw, `$_post[]` is not a method... it's an array.

Comment: @Cristian, good notice! And `[]` is an operator just like in `Java`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very basic of PHP. [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is super-global array of PHP that stores data that was sent to a particular script using POST method.

You can use it as any other [PHP array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Code below will output all the keys of $_POST and corresponding values:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ' = ' . var_export($value, true);
}
```

If you know which key you need exactly, you can get it using `[]` on array like so:

```
$my_value = $_POST['my_post_field_sent_by_android_app'];
```

Comment: for debugging purpose a single line `var_dump($_POST)` could be enough

Comment: sure. But I persoanlly like [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) more. It is not that informative as `var_dump` is, though.